# how to set origin google add-ons for doc files in console

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to develop google add-ons almost it's already done, when i getting access token using

```
   gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {gapi.auth2.init({client_id:'<client_id>'});
     });
```

and passing that token in header to export google drive file using  `gapi.client.drive.files.export` method it's working as expected but if I share my doc to other and do same thing using who's account then getting origin issue
I set javascript origin in console
origin: `https://n-7x3isqjjteft3mjfvl2mimyt2jybyz72pefibra-1lu-script.googleusercontent.com`

It's working for my account but not other please let me know how can i resolved this issue?